# Why is dataverse taking so long to answer to simple requests?

Tags: .net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I'm using [Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/) to do requests on my dynamics 365 environment and every request takes a long time to finish, but the requests are processed nearly instantly on dataverse side. My project is .net core 5.

For exemple, in this picture you can see that it takes 17 seconds for the creation of a Contact on my project side (from sending request to receiving response):
[image: Azure function console logging]

There is the code with loggings:
[image: Create Contact code]

However, I see on dataverse side that the creation is done in less than a second:
[image: Contact created on]

Why is it taking so long to return a response knowing that the contact has been created nearly instantly?

Would it be faster to create the contact without the entity references and then update it? If so, why?

Comment: What is the type of _serviceClient in your example? Also you are aware that Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client is an alpha/beta status library? You should use Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly (but that doesn't work in .NET core or .NET 5, so can only used in Azure Functions 1.0))

Comment: I just put everything on my .net core 5.0 project. I scrapped the Azure function. Knowing that this library is the only one that works with .net core 5.0, do you have a REAL explanation or solution for me?